# Disable operator= and copy constructor

Tags: c++

Is there a way to disable operator= and copy constructor and allow using `std::move()` only?
I know that i can do

```
foo& operator= (const foo&) = delete;
foo(const foo&) = delete;
```

but this will disable std::move too.

**What i want is to block copying of this class**
and allow only `foo foo2 = std::move(foo1);`

Btw. I have private contructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `defaulted` special member functions:

```
foo(foo&&) = default;
foo& operator=(foo&&) = default;
```

Comment: `foo(foo&&) = default;` : Error invalid type for defaulted contructor

Comment: You can also make them private, and provide only the declaration, not the definition. This is only a workaround if your compiler doesn't support c++11 or the `default`/`delete` features.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx "Rvalue references" "defaulted and deleted functions"

Comment: Or better yet, note 2 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457344.aspx